# How to enter value into drop-down-menu on webpage using Perl and Mechanize

Tags: html, perl, firefox, drop-down-menu, mechanize

I have this drop down menu on a site that I would like to enter data into a drop down menu using **Perl** and `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` and here is the section of the page source that the drop down is located:

```
<select name="skuAndSize"
                  class="exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown "
                  data-tooltiptext="Select a Size" required="required"
                  data-error="Select a Size" >
            <option class="exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock" value=""></option>


                <option class="exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock"
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579670:6"
                      data-label="(6)">
                                  6
                </option>

                <option class="exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock"
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579671:6.5"
                      data-label="(6.5)">
                                  6.5
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579672:7"
                      data-label="(7)">
                                  7
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579673:7.5"
                      data-label="(7.5)">
                                  7.5
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579674:8"
                      data-label="(8)">
                                  8
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579675:8.5"
                      data-label="(8.5)">
                                  8.5
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579676:9"
                      data-label="(9)">
                                  9
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579677:9.5"
                      data-label="(9.5)">
                                  9.5
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579678:10"
                      data-label="(10)">
                                  10
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579679:10.5"
                      data-label="(10.5)">
                                  10.5
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579680:11"
                      data-label="(11)">
                                  11
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579681:11.5"
                      data-label="(11.5)">
                                  11.5
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579682:12"
                      data-label="(12)">
                                  12
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579683:12.5"
                      data-label="(12.5)">
                                  12.5
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579684:13"
                      data-label="(13)">
                                  13
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579685:14"
                      data-label="(14)">
                                  14
                </option>

                <option 
                      name="skuId"
                      value="3579686:15"
                      data-label="(15)">
                                  15
                </option>


          </select>
```

**I have to select the `10` option not knowing the value only the data-label.**
My current method of doing so is entering `10` into the `skuAndSize` value and that does not seem to work.
**Does anyone know how I should go about doing this?** Thank you.